# use proxy from a list

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a program which neeeds to use a proxy 3 times then move onto the next proxy in a list and so on. the user will enter their proxy list into a list/textfile and the program will use the first in the list and then carry on through the list until it gets to the end.

How do i get the proxy details from the list and use them using httpwebrequest? i have no problem using a proxy if i set it within the code but dont know how to get it to work through the list

basically it is like this:
user enters a list of proxies into a text file
program uses first proxy in list 3 times then moves onto next.
this repeats until finished.

Comment: `foreach (Proxy proxy in proxies)` is not enough? I don't understand: you say "*i have no problem using a proxy if i set it within the code*", so you're telling us you don't know how to extract items from a list?

Comment: exactly! i have no idea how do extract from list as you just stated. I am pretty new to c# so sorry if this is a dumb question

Answer (score 0):

I see your comment now, so try this:

```
foreach (string proxy in proxies) // proxies is the list entered by user
{
    // proxy is the proxy you must try for three times;
    bool proxy_works = test_proxy(); // test function you must write
    // if you need to find first working proxy and then stop
    // use next statements, on the contrary remove them 
    // and you'll travel the whole list
    if (proxy_works)
    {
        // do here what you need (save working proxy?!?)
        break;
    }
}
```

If your user enters proxies separated by comma (for example) you can build proxies as follows:

```
string[] proxies = strProxy.Split(",".ToCharArray(), 
                                  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

or if you want to read from file:

```
string[] proxies = File.ReadAllLines(file_path);
```

If every proxy is done as `host_name:port` you can do

```
string vars = proxy.Split(':'.ToCharArray());
if (vars.Length == 2) 
{
    string MyProxyHostString = vars[0];
    int MyProxyPort = int.Parse(vars[1]); // Better if you use int.TryParse method
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i will try this tomorrow, bit late with me now :)

Comment: ok, but I'm going to help you in 9 hours, because it's late for me too :)

Comment: another dumb question i guess.... how to use string read with your last example with this: HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy (MyProxyHostString, MyProxyPort);